# Canvas LMS is extremely slow and exhausting CPU cycles. What can be the cause and how can it be resolved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bitnami

When many users connect to my Canvas LMS, it becomes painfully slow and unresponsive. I strongly believe it is not a resources issue; potentially a configuration issue such that the software is not utilizing the hardware properly. I have checked the log files and can't seem to figure out the problem. It is a Bitnami installation and is based on Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQl. Anyone who has encountered and resolved this problem?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please note that CanvasLMS requires a lot of memory to work properly. I suggest you check the resources of the instance by running these commands: `df -H; free -m; top`. If you have enough free disk and RAM memory available, please take a look at the Apache's (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs) and app's (/opt/bitnami/apps/canvaslms/htdocs) logs to get more information.  Apart from that, please check if there are malicious requests in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/access_log` file to ensure there is not any bot/attacker accessing your site.

Comment: I have deployed a canvas LMS application and so far everything is fine except for a few issues. The goal is to leverage google authentication for logins. So far I have made a tremendous progress. However, the challenge is, when I click on Sign In with Google, I get redirected to the Gmail login screen but then afterwards, the application throws an error indicating that the user email does not exist in the system. I can confirm for sure that the email is registered in the application and I am even able to successfully login in with the same email and password.